# print elements of std:: list using iterator c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to iterate through a `std::list` (containing) objects and print some methods but the compiler complaints that 
`'print': is not a member of 'std::shared_ptr<A>'` However if i create an object `std::shared_ptr<A> animal(*it);` and call `animal.print()` it will work just fine why is that? below is the function i'm having trouble with (it's also a small portion of my very large program involving lots of polymorphism)

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Hand& _hand) {         

            std::list< std::shared_ptr<A>>::const_iterator it = _hand.hand.begin();    
            std::shared_ptr<A> animal(*it);  
             animal.print(); //workss  
            while (it != _hand.hand.end()) {            
            it->print();   //doesn't work
                ++it;


            }

     return out;}
```

The `list` i'm iterating through is of type `A` (which is abstract) and contain objects of it's derived classes.

Comment: AFAIK `animal.print();` shouldn't work.

Comment: The compiler didn't complain!

Comment: It should have done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(*it)` returns a smart pointer reference, so you need to dereference it again.

`(**it).print()` or `(*it)->print()`

Or you may find this neater if you want to call several functions in a row: `const auto& animal = **it; animal.print();`

Comment: Stop on. Thanks will accept this answer in 6 mins. Thank you very much

Comment: @Bobby by any chance you are using SO on a mobile ? Felt like Spot on got changed to Stop on. lol

Comment: Using the new range-based for loops would also be an option. for (auto &hand : _hand.hand) hand->print().